# in ubuntu 11.10 IDE like dreamweaver for PHP with design mode

Tags: php, ide, web-development

I know that this question is already asked here, but I did not find any free IDE like dreamweaver which have facility to view design mode with PHP+HTML code.

I am previously worked on windows machine and used dreamweave, now I moved to ubuntu 11.10 and I need IDE like dreamweaver. Currently I have used Geany and Eclipse but none of them has facility of design mode. Is there any add-on available for Geany or Eclipse then please give it link to me.

I am new to ubuntu so, did not have much knowledge of it and because of it I am here for answer.

Thanks in advance.

Pkachhia

Comment: No any expert advice?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2**: From the stuff I just read through, maybe CKEditor is your best bet at the moment; It is available under the GPL as well as a commercial license, written in javascript -- there are special versions to integrate it as editor/ide in drupal joomla and java-webapplications. http://ckeditor.com/

**Edit**: I did dig a bit deeper; KompoZer and it's ancestor Nvu are rather old; (One of) The author(s) has a new project: bluegriffon -- but I don't know if it supports php.

---

Maybe KompoZer is to your liking: http://kompozer.net/; there is a PPA: https://launchpad.net/~giuseppe-iuculano/+archive/ppa

It uses gecko to render.

I never used it, so I can't endorse it; i just found it -- and it's free and open source.

Comment: Finally I got the reply, I have checked it and inform you.

Comment: To set Kompozer up to handle php-files (at least locally), you apparently need an addon named HandCoder; maybe this post here: http://webgrrrl.net/archives/kompozer-cant-open-php-files-in-ubuntu-yes-it-can.htm helps you to get there